# Select values from different rows in one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE MAIN (
    [ID] INT PRIMARY KEY,
    [TIMESTAMP] DATETIME,
    [NAME] VARCHAR(15)
    );

CREATE TABLE SEC (
    [ID] INT PRIMARY KEY,
    [TIMESTAMP] DATETIME,
    [VAL] INT,
    [TYPE] VARCHAR(10)
    );
```

I would like to select values from both tables. Data in second table has a different values in `type` column but has the same timestamp as the `main` table data.

```
SELECT M.[TIMESTAMP], [NAME], [VAL] AS 'VAL_TYPE_1', [VAL] AS 'VAL_TYPE_2'
FROM MAIN M
LEFT JOIN SEC S ON M.TIMESTAMP = S.TIMESTAMP
WHERE S.TYPE = 'TYPE_1' OR S.TYPE = 'TYPE_2';
```

For all timestamps from `main` table I would like to get name and value of the `TYPE_1` (NULL if it does not exist) and value of the `TYPE_2` (or NULL if it does not exist). What should I change?

Comment: Your question is unclear--some sample data would help but i suspect you need a case statement like `case when [val] = <somecondition> then [val] end as Type_1`

Comment: First, you should fully qualify all of your fields (i.e. m.val). Second, what is wrong with what you have written so far? That query you have will give you the nulls you seek.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is often done via a [CASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql)

For example:

```
SELECT M.[TIMESTAMP], M.[NAME], 
CASE WHEN S.TYPE = 'TYPE_1' THEN S.[VAL] END AS [VAL_TYPE_1], 
CASE WHEN S.TYPE = 'TYPE_2' THEN S.[VAL] END AS [VAL_TYPE_2]
FROM MAIN M
LEFT JOIN SEC S ON M.TIMESTAMP = S.TIMESTAMP
WHERE S.TYPE IN('TYPE_1','TYPE_2');
```

And if you want to group by on the TIMESTAMP and NAME, that's also possible

```
SELECT M.[TIMESTAMP], M.[NAME], 
MAX(CASE WHEN S.TYPE = 'TYPE_1' THEN S.[VAL] END) AS [VAL_TYPE_1],  
MAX(CASE WHEN S.TYPE = 'TYPE_2' THEN S.[VAL] END) AS [VAL_TYPE_2] 
FROM MAIN M
LEFT JOIN SEC S ON M.TIMESTAMP = S.TIMESTAMP
WHERE S.TYPE IN('TYPE_1','TYPE_2')
GROUP BY M.[TIMESTAMP], M.[NAME];
```

Comment: this is way better than my query. would have made two joins. so yours has better performance

Comment: The second one is the one I wanted to get!

Comment: @EstebanP. Well, it's an old sql trick used to pivot row data to columns before [PIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot) existed. :)

Answer (score 0):

if i undstood right, you need something like this:

```
SELECT M.[TIMESTAMP]
      ,M.[NAME]
      ,S1.[VAL] AS 'VAL_TYPE_1'
      ,S2.[VAL] AS 'VAL_TYPE_2'
FROM MAIN M
LEFT JOIN SEC S1 ON M.TIMESTAMP = S1.TIMESTAMP
AND S1.TYPE = 'TYPE_1' 
LEFT JOIN SEC S2 ON M.TIMESTAMP = S2.TIMESTAMP
AND S2.TYPE = 'TYPE_2';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get this by simple union query i think. Hope this helps

```
SELECT M.[TIMESTAMP], [NAME], [VAL] AS 'VAL_TYPE_1', NULL 'VAL_TYPE_2'
FROM MAIN M
LEFT JOIN SEC S ON M.TIMESTAMP = S.TIMESTAMP
WHERE S.TYPE = 'TYPE_1' 

UNION ALL 

SELECT M.[TIMESTAMP], [NAME], NULL 'VAL_TYPE_1' , [VAL] AS 'VAL_TYPE_2'
FROM MAIN M
LEFT JOIN SEC S ON M.TIMESTAMP = S.TIMESTAMP
WHERE S.TYPE = 'TYPE_2'
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need something like:

```
SELECT          M.[TIMESTAMP],
                [NAME],
                T1.[VAL] AS 'VAL_TYPE_1',
                T2.[VAL] AS 'VAL_TYPE_2'
FROM            MAIN M
LEFT OUTER JOIN SEC T1
             ON M.TIMESTAMP = T1.TIMESTAMP
            AND T1.TYPE = 'TYPE_1'
LEFT OUTER JOIN SEC T2
             ON M.TIMESTAMP = T2.TIMESTAMP
            AND T2.TYPE = 'TYPE_2';
```